# Is there a way to get the exact indexOf an element in a big html string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill

I am working on an app with vue.js and quill.js in which I am creating some documents.
The content of a document is stored in `document.content` which is one giant string with a bunch of html tags in it coming straight from quill.js.

When previewing the document I'm rendering the big html string inside a div with v-html attribute like this:

```
<div v-html="document.content"></div>
```

i.e.

```
document.content = "<p>Hello</p><p>World</p><p>Hello World</p><p>Hello</p>"
```

It's rendereded as (you get the idea):

```
<div data-v-4ee08204>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

The **question** is:
When clicking somewhere inside the div is there a way to get the exact index of the character/word/element I've clicked on (because I need to add a comment to it)?

I've tried to attach a click listener to the div, getting the outerHTML of the target element and trying to get the indexOf document.content, but it's not always working, because there can be similar stuff inside the big string like `<p>Hello</p>` twice and it will get the first one only.

It's possible that my whole approach is wrong, but I'm not really sure.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Is it always a <p>? Where does this content come from?

Comment: `event.target` will get you the element that caused an event, so you can attach click handler to the document's body and capture whatever you click on.

Comment: You need to parse the HTML string into your own DOM, add a `data-uuid` to each element and render the result. That way you can easily identify clicked elements.

Comment: However, what exactly does "add a comment to it" mean here? Why do you need the index to do something to the element?

Comment: Should the "comments" you add be re-attachable to the content once it's rendered again?

Comment: The add a comment part is actually not important now, I'm just going to add comments in the app later and that's why I need the indexes.

Comment: As I stated in my comment below Telmo's answer, getting the String.indexOf is most likely not suitable to solve your actual problem. You *do* need to tell us which actual problem you think you're going to solve by getting the index. See here: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. I am just trying to get the index and assign it to another object (which will be the comment), and to know that this comment is associated with this exact position in the document.content string later when I'm working with them. Nothing more. 

Anyway, I like your idea of parsing the string to the DOM and adding data-uuid to each element and I'm going to try it. Thanks.

Comment: @lucas - no it's not always a <p>. It's coming from quill.js - it could be everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to clone the parent element, add the comment using DOM manipulation and then use the parent element's innerHTML, here is an example:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
parent.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.target.classList.add('toBeModified');

  const clone = parent.cloneNode(true);
  const node = clone.querySelector('.toBeModified');
  const comment = document.createElement('span');
  comment.textContent = '(edited)';
  node.appendChild(comment);
  node.classList.remove('toBeModified');
  event.target.classList.remove('toBeModified');

  console.log(clone.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

What this does is to add a class (`toBeModified`) to the clicked element so it can be easily found once the parent is cloned.

Comment: Not exactly on point, but you gave me a good starting point and I've managed to do what I needed based on your answer! Thanks :)